# Big-0 notations Order of Magnitude

Tags: java, big-o

I'm doing some homework and just want to make sure I am on the right track.

The question is:

> Describe the order of magnitude of each of the following functions using Big-O notation.

```
 1) N^2 + 3N               =   my answer   O(N^2)
 2) 3N^2 + N                =   my answer   O(N^2)
 3) N^5 + 100N^3 + 245     =    my answer   O(N^5)
 4) 3Nlog2N + N^2           –   my answer  O(N^2)
 5) 1 + N + N^2 + N^3 + N^4 =   my answer   O(N^4)
 6) (N * (N – 1)) / 2       -   my answer   O(N^2)
```

Am I doing this right? Any suggestions?

Comment: The first two `O` are correct, check the rest against those.

Comment: What do your 3rd and 4th answers mean?

Comment: @ArtistOfProgramming, the first 3 is correct but 4th and 5th is wrong.

Comment: after edit the question looks more clear... and agree with @The Elite Gentleman , all are correct except 4 and 5...

Comment: By `log^2 N` do you mean `log(log(N))` If you are, its an obscure notation and not correct here. Perhaps you mean `log2 N` (You have to decide if its correct, I am just saying it least it means something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Big-O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)'s Order of magnitude is the one with the highest power (because they are, in most cases, the most computationally expensive function). So, you will have to see, in your formula, which function is most computationally expensive to do.

The first 2 is correct. The other 3, well.... ;)

---

Update: Question 1, 2, 3 and 6 are correct.